# Expo Application - after install builded .apk file application stuck on Splash Screen

Tags: android, react-native, expo, screen, splash-screen

Application written with Expo. When the app runs locally in developer mode or production mode all works well on the device emulator. But after the application is built as .apk and installed on an emulator or real device, the application is stuck on the Splash Screen.

## package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "expo": "~49.0.8",
    "expo-asset": "~8.10.1",
    "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
    "expo-document-picker": "~11.5.4",
    "expo-file-system": "~15.4.4",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-sqlite": "~11.3.3",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "~2.4.0",
    "expo-sharing": "~11.5.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-calendar-picker": "^7.1.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-popup-menu": "^0.16.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.27.0",
    "react-native-select-dropdown": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  }
```

## eas.js

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 5.7.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      },
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview2": {
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      }
    },
    "preview3": {
      "developmentClient": true
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

## App.js

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const DrawerNavigation = () => {
    return (
        <Drawer.Navigator screenOptions={() => {
            return {
                headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: Colors.primary
                },
                drawerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: Colors.primary,
                    width: "50%"
                },
                drawerActiveTintColor: Colors.action,
                unmountOnBlur: true
            }
        }}>
            <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{headerTitle: "Hello"}}/>
            <Drawer.Screen name="Recipes" component={RecipesScreen}/>
            <Drawer.Screen name="RecipeCreation" component={RecipeCreationScreen} options={{title: "New Recipe"}}/>
            <Drawer.Screen name="Favorites" component={FavoritesScreen}/>
            <Drawer.Screen name="ShoppingList" component={ShoppingListScreen} options={{title: "Shopping List"}}/>
            <Drawer.Screen name="MealPlanner" component={MealPlannerScreen} options={{title: "Meal Planner"}}/>
            <Drawer.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen}/>
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    );
};

const MainNavigation = () => {
    return (
        <MenuProvider>
            <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={(props) => {
                return {
                    headerShown: props.route.name === "RecipeDetails",
                    headerStyle: {
                        backgroundColor: Colors.primary
                    }
                };
            }}>
                <Stack.Screen name="RecipeList" component={DrawerNavigation}/>
                <Stack.Screen name="RecipeDetails" component={RecipeDetailsScreen}/>
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </MenuProvider>
    );
};

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();
export default function App() {

    const [appIsReady, setAppIsReady] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function prepare() {
            try {
                await Font.loadAsync({
                    'open-sans': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf'),
                    'opes-sans-bold': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf')
                });
                await init();
                await initShopping();
                await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
            } catch (e) {
                console.warn(e);
            } finally {
                // Tell the application to render
                setAppIsReady(true);
            }
        }

        prepare();
    }, []);

    const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
        if (appIsReady) {
            await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
        }
    }, [appIsReady]);

    if (!appIsReady) {
        return null;
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container} onLayout={onLayoutRootView}>
            <StatusBar style="auto"/>
            <NavigationContainer>
                <MainNavigation/>
            </NavigationContainer>
        </View>
    );
}
```

I didn't find any issue. I tried removing the expo-splash-screen and this didn't help me. The application is stuck with a white screen. If comment  NavigationContainer and MainNavigation application run well. But I can't understand where the problem is.

Comment: Can you share the code on the homescreen where you implement the splashscreen?

Comment: You should edit your question and add the code, not create an answer

Comment: Part of App.js added

Comment: @Refilon I update description

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping me solve my issue. Oyy. Nobody helped me.
I solved the issue. Problem was with initialRouteName="RecipeList". I forgot to add it. Maybe this can help someone.

```
<Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="RecipeList">
```